# Is it possible to print a sorted dictionary by value, but if the value are the same, the keys go in alphabetical order

Tags: python

Is this possible?

I have tried this:

```
for key in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
        values = ", ". join(dictionary[key])
        print(f"{key} {values}")
```

But this doesn't account for if the value are equal.

Comment: What is your expected result if values are equal? Please include example input and example output

Answer (score 2):

This example compares tuples (values, key), so if two values are equal, the key of the dictionary will be used to sort it:

```py
dictionary = {
    'c': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'a': 1,
}
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
# [('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
d = {"c": 3, "a": 1, "e": 2, "d": 2}

print(sorted((value,key) for (key,value) in d.items()))
```

#output

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'd'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'c')]
```